# CreateIfNotExists forgets to copy a table

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm calling CreateIfNotExists on my EF database object to create the SQL CE file if it doesn't already exist. Up until now it has worked wonderfully. I've created a new table and now when it creates the file it does so without the new table. What is going on?

I tried deleting and re-adding the table and it does the same thing.

Comment: You didn't share any code. Does the context know about the new entity? Also, you state you're using CreateIfNotExists. That doesn't care if your model changes, it only cares if a database already exists with the name it's looking for. Are you doing something manually to delete it so next time you run your app it won't exist and will be created?

Comment: Yes, the context is a database-first and knows about the new table. I'm guessing this was a bug. I undid all of my changes to the database file and the EF mappings and redid all of the work and now it magically works. That was a painful experience. 

I didn't provide any code because it was all generated code. I could have provided my database schema I suppose, but it's very standard stuff.

Comment: Why did someone vote to close this question?

Comment: I was manually deleted the database file, yes.